# Closure and convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with lower limit topology and denote it by $\mathbb{R}_l$, let $A \subset \mathbb{R}_l$. I want to prove that $x \in \bar{A}$ if and only if there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that $x_n \geq x$ and $\vert x_n - x \vert \to 0$. I know that $x \in \bar{A}$ if and only if every neighborhood $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$. But I'm confused about the wording of $x_n \geq x$ and $\vert x_n - x \vert \to 0$.

Comment: consider neighborhoods $[x,x+\frac1k)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something to consider: If $x_n \to x$ in the lower limit topology then we know that for every open neighborhood, $U$ of $x$, there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ that $x_n \in U$. In particular, the sets $\left[x,x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ are open for every $n$ so if there were infinitely many $x_n$ such that $x_n < x$, then $x_n$ would NOT converge to $x$ because there would be no point in the sequence for which all subsequent terms would be in $U$ since there would always be some later term $x_m < x \implies x_m \notin U$. Hence, we must have that there is some $N$ such that $x_n \ge x$ for all $n \ge N$.

Considering the same sets of the form $\left[x,x+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ also reveals that if $x_n \to x$ then for every $k$, there is some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ that $x_n \in \left[x,x+\frac{1}{k}\right)$. Thus we must have that $|x_n - x| \to 0$.